# How can I retrieve sort property and direction from a Spring Data Pageable?

Tags: java, spring-data

I am building an API that will call another API and return results. The API I am calling has a paging and sorting mechanism that requires adding the following query params to the URL:

```
?pageNumber=1&pageSize=20&sortField=id&sortDirection=asc
```

Now, I would like my API to use a Spring Pageable object as a parameter in the controller method, so, according to Spring Docs the URL passed to my new API will be:

```
?page=1&size=20&sort=id,asc
```

Therefore, in order to map the received pageable object to the required query params that I need to pass to the uinderlying API I need to retrieve the paging and sorting information from the Pageable object. 
As for the `pageSize` and `pageNumber` it is pretty straight forward:

```
pageable.getPageNumber()
pageable.getPageSize()
```

But how can I retrieve sortField and sortDirection?

`pageable.getSort()` returns the Sort object, from which I could not find a way to retrieve what i need - the sortField value (string with property name) and sortDirection value (asc or desc)

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Pageable::getSort`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html#getSort--) will give you a [`Sort`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html), and that is an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) of [`Sort.Order`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.Order.html)s. You need to iterate over each of these. They contain the properties you're looking for.

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "abc");

for (Sort.Order order : sort)
{
    System.out.println("Property: " + order.getProperty());
    System.out.println("Direction: " + order.getDirection());
}
```

Prints

```
Property: abc
Direction: ASC
```

Comment: Great answer! Minor detail: `Sort` implements `Streamable<Order>` so that you can do the following: `Sort.by("firstname").forEach(System.out::println);`. You can also `map(…)`, `filter(…)` etc.